# Larger than or smaller than decision

Tags: symbols

This is my first time using Latex, is there a way to write an equation like this?[image: ?]

I can't find that symbol. Thank you very much!

Comment: Like this? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$A\gtrless B$

\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is Gonzalo's comment helpful? Otherwise, which symbol are you referring to that you can't find? This question might be helpful if you cannot find a particular symbol: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: Thank you, his answer was very helpful. I will use that link as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\Lambda(x)\underset{FP}{\overset{TP}{\gtrless}} T^{\ast}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, define a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\gldec[2]{
\underset{#1}{\overset{#2}{\gtrless}}
}

\begin{document}

$\Lambda(x)\gldec{FP}{TP} T^{\ast}$

\end{document}
```

Or (should "FP" and "TP" be fixed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\gldec{
\underset{FP}{\overset{TP}{\gtrless}}
}

\begin{document}

$\Lambda(x)\gldec T^{\ast}$

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure of the font that should be used for "FP" and "TP", but that is up to their meaning; is they should be treated like text, then `\text{FP}` and `\text{TP}` should be used.

Comment: Followup to @GonzaloMedina 's answer. If `F` and `P` represent variables, keep them as they are so they are italicized and spaced properly. If they are text, use `\text{FP}`. (A general principle for text in equations.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I added a little remark to my answer. Thanks!